# only print the solution in docplex solve()

Tags: python, docplex

Using `from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel` I have written a docplex code.
Model defenition is as follows.

```
mdl = CpoModel(name="HouseBuilding")
```

But by the solve() function it is printing unnecessary output with the solution at last.

```
msol = mdl.solve(TimeLimit=10)
```

I believe it is printing below things
.

```
solve status,
solver parameters,
solver information
output log
```

Sample output as follows.How should I avoid print these information but only the solution.

```
! -------------------------------------------------- CP Optimizer 12.10.0.0 --
 ! Maximization problem - 153 variables, 123 constraints
 ! TimeLimit            = 10
 ! Initial process time : 0.00s (0.00s extraction + 0.00s propagation)
 !  . Log search space  : 330.1 (before), 330.1 (after)
 !  . Memory usage      : 926.0 kB (before), 926.0 kB (after)
 ! Using parallel search with 4 workers.
 ! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 !          Best Branches  Non-fixed    W       Branch decision
                        0        153                 -
 + New bound is 385
 ! Using iterative diving.
 ! Using temporal relaxation.
                        0        153    1            -
 + New bound is 372
 *           309      155  0.12s        1      (gap is 20.39%)
 *           313      387  0.12s        1      (gap is 18.85%)
 *           315      552  0.12s        1      (gap is 18.10%)
             315     1000          2    1   F         !presenceOf(H4-facade(Jack))
 *           340     1480  0.12s        1      (gap is 9.41%)
             340     2000          2    1       230  = startOf(H3-garden(Jim))
 *           346     2343  0.12s        1      (gap is 7.51%)
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need set the log_output parameter to delete this unnecessary output

```py
msol = mdl.solve(TimeLimit=10, log_output=False)
```

To print objetive value (aka solution):

```py
print(msol.objective_value)
```

Finally, if you need to access the solution of your variables, you must iterare your Narray variable and use:

```py
msol[var_name[(i, j, ... , etc. )]]))
```

I hope this answer will be helpful to you and sorry for my English.

Comment: In addition you can use msol.display() to show the objetive and variables values